# What is the best AI algorithm for time based binary prediction

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

What is the best AI algorithm for time based binary prediction based on a database of previous results? With all the algorithms out there, i'm looking for advice on the best algorithm to train itself to predict the next binary number of an incomplete "real time" data set based off a database "data set."

Example data sets that were previously recorded and stored

```
Binary Data Set 1  100**110111**0010111000111010101

Binary Data Set 2  0110010001101110110**110111**000

Binary Data Set 3  0010110010**110111**1001011011011000
```

In each set we find the pattern 110111 and the next event

```
Set 1 -  110111  Next event is  0

Set 2 -  110111  Next event is  0

Set 3 -  110111  Next event is  1
```

In 2 data sets, the next event was a 0, in 1 data set the next event was a 1. So in our very tiny example...if this pattern shows up, we would make a prediction of 0 because it shows up 66% of the time. But the algorithm would train itself to make this decision.

Realtime - In real time the binary events come in 1 per second. We have the received the following incomplete data and wish to predict what is next           1000010000**110111**  What algorithm is best suited to predict what is next?

Thank you for any assistance!!

Comment: Your question doesn't fit here particularly well, but is a worthy question.  Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues

Comment: I don't get it. Count how often you get 1 or 0 as the next bit and predict the one that came more often. How would that count as artificial intelligence?

Comment: You really should attempt a solution and include your work so far...

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Over the past 3 years, i've written 4 projects attempting to solve this problem without AI. I've always attempted to apply my rules to the data, when i'm hoping AI will help me mine out what rules are needed. So i'm shifting focus and just wanted to make sure i'm learning about the correct algorithm to solve my problem. Laurenz - A valid question but i'm not matching just one pattern. I want any pattern of 1's and 0's from lengths of 3 bits to ...nbits  It can be done with "manual" matching, i've done it, i'm just shifting my focus to hopefully improve. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurrent neural networks and especially LSTM (Long-short-term-memory) networks are used for time series prediction. In your case, the data is quite simple and can be modelled easily. 
Look at this [The magic of LSTM networks](https://medium.com/datathings/the-magic-of-lstm-neural-networks-6775e8b540cd)

Comment: Thank you very much Trifon! I've written this project multiple times doing "manual" pattern matching and counting. That kind of analysis comes with a flaw, it assumes "MY" rules are correct. When what I wish to find out is "what rules are correct for this problem." When I started to read about the various algorithms it was apparent that I needed the right algorithm for the right job. I really appreciate your response, I will save me a bunch of research time getting started!